# Polymer paper-spinner change color through class with data-binding

Tags: data-binding, styles, polymer, web-component

I use a polymer paper-spinner inside my web-component:

```
<dom-module id="custom-spinner">
  <style include = 'custom-spinner-styles'>

    paper-spinner.yellow{
      --paper-spinner-layer-1-color: yellow;
      --paper-spinner-layer-2-color: yellow;
      --paper-spinner-layer-3-color: yellow;
      --paper-spinner-layer-4-color: yellow;
    }

  </style>

  <template> 
    <div class = "loader">
      <paper-spinner class$="{{color}}"></paper-spinner>
    </div>

    <content>
    </content>
  </template>

</dom-module>

<script>
  etc....
</script>
```

I use it like this:

```
<custom-spinner color = "yellow" size = "200px" fade-in-sp = "500" fade-out-sp = "400"></custom-spinner>
```

Now the problem is, that the data-binding works and the paper-spinners class is set to yellow, but the styles are not applied.

If I set `'yellow'` directly it works perfectly:

```
<paper-spinner class="yellow"></paper-spinner>
```

Any ideas where the problem is?

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did my example helped you?

Comment: @PascalGula Hello, Pascal I didn't tryed it out yet(lot of other thingss to do), I'll try it this weekend and give you a feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I am using data-binding for Styling in my [`gold-password-input`](http://metanov.github.io/gold-password-input/) and it is working like this:

```
  .None {
    color: var(--gold-password-input-strength-meter-none-color, --paper-grey-700) !important;
  }
  .VeryWeak {
    color: var(--gold-password-input-strength-meter-veryweak-color, --paper-red-700) !important;
  }
  .Weak {
    color: var(--gold-password-input-strength-meter-weak-color, --paper-orange-700) !important;
  }
  .Medium {
    color: var(--gold-password-input-strength-meter-medium-color, --paper-yellow-700) !important;
  }
  .Strong {
    color: var(--gold-password-input-strength-meter-strong-color, --paper-blue-700) !important;
  }
  .VeryStrong {
    color: var(--gold-password-input-strength-meter-verystrong-color, --paper-green-700) !important;
  }
```

and

```
<span id="strengthLabel">
  [[strengthMeterLabels.Label]]:
  <span class$=[[_strengthMeterScore]]>[[_computeStrengthMeterLabel(_strengthMeterScore)]]</span>
  <paper-icon-button icon="info" alt="info" disabled noink></paper-icon-button>
</span>
```